# R-script reading fixed width file of large data from NOAA FTP only grabbing partial table

Tags: r, web-scraping, noaa

Hello new to R so I apologize in advance if this is a simple fix.

I am attempting to grab precipitation data from NOAA's database once a day, this function was working perfectly for a few months but NOAA increased the size of the tables and now I am only being returned partial tables: starting from the first line but with different ending lines each run. It seems as if the data is being scraped before the entire table has loaded. If there is any advice on how to grab the entire table that would be great.

Here is the code I am using that had worked in the past, but now one run will grab all lines of code while others stop half way/quarter/etc.

```
Temp = read.fwf("ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/all/USW00054779.dly",
                widths = c(11, 4, 2, 4, rep(c(5, 1, 1, 1),31)))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should add a few bits more of details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
ghcn_url <- "ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/all/USW00054779.dly"
ghcn_fil <- basename(ghcn_url)

if (!file.exists(ghcn_fil)) download.file(ghcn_url, ghcn_fil)

tmp <- read.fwf(ghcn_fil, widths = c(11, 4, 2, 4, rep(c(5, 1, 1, 1), 31)))
```

This has the other benefit of being kind to the remote server in the event your data processing (or other issues) force a reprocessing of the target file (i.e. you can read the local copy vs grab it again).

This is also not web scraping. It's reading a fixed-width file. You should probably change the title.